# NativeScript - Change Label into TextView/TextField with a Button

Tags: nativescript

I am learning to make an app in NativeScript (Angular 2). In my item page, I want to have a button so that when I press it, I can change **Label** into **TextView/TextField** for editing the information of the item.

I know that I can use **editable** in **TextView** but I still want to know if it is feasible to have the button with that functionality. Thank you !!

***item.component.html:***

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label class="h3" text="Name: {{ item.get_name() }}" textWrap="true">
    </Label>
    <Label class="h3" text="Credit: {{ item.get_credit() }}"></Label>
    <Button class="btn" text="Edit" (tap)="change()"></Button>
</StackLayout>

<!-- After pressing the button -->
<StackLayout>
    <TextView class="h3" [text]="item.get_name()" textWrap="true">
    </TextView>
    <TextView class="h3" [text]="item.get_credit()"></TextView>
    <Button class="btn" text="Save" (tap)="change()"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: For something like this I usually just change the visibility of the controls.  You could, for example, have a text field that overlays the label (may need a GridLayout to do this).  Tapping the button would hide the label and display the text field, and both could be bound to the same variable.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in many ways, but one common way is by changing visibility of control and binding it to a variable / property in the code behind.

in your component html:

Then on your component ts or code-behind you can handle it in the change method:

```
class MyComponentSample {
   isLabelMode: boolean = true; // Set to true if you want label to show by default or false if TextView as default

   change() {
      this.isLabelMode = !isLabelMode; // Basically you are toggling the mode here.
   }
}
```